# Passing stats to geoms with geom_violin in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

The following code:

```
library(ggplot2)
theData <- data.frame(category <- sample(LETTERS[1:3], 1000, replace = T),
                  value <- rnorm(1000))
thePlot <- ggplot(theData,
              aes(x = category, y = value))
thePlot <- thePlot + geom_violin(fill = "BLACK")
thePlot <- thePlot + coord_flip()
print(thePlot)
```

will produce this plot:

[image: violin plot example]

But I would like to achieve an effect whereby the alpha value of the fill (and colour, ideally) of each violin density decreases in less-dense areas. That is, the violin shape fades into the background where the height of the curve is small, but is dark and opaque where the curve is tall. Something like this type of effect:

[image: alpha fade example]

Unfortunately, those coefficient plots are produced by use of a pretty ugly hack, and given the flexibility of the new geom_violin, I am wondering if there is a straightforward way to implement this alpha fade in the use of geom_violin.

Thanks for any insight you can offer!

Comment: Not easily. The violins themselves are drawn as a filled polygon, which can only have a single fill color. It may be possible to pull out the data that defines the violin (the density estimate) and then plot separate segments (with separate colors/alphas), but you would have to build up something yourself to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer; I feared that this might be the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inspired at @wch's answer, I decided to take another crack at this.  This was as close as I got:

```
ggplot(theData, aes(x = category, y = value)) +
    stat_ydensity(geom="segment", aes(xend=..x..+..scaled../2, 
        yend=..y.., alpha=..scaled..), size=2, trim=FALSE) +
    stat_ydensity(geom="segment", aes(xend=..x..-..scaled../2, 
        yend=..y.., alpha=..scaled..), size=2, trim=FALSE) +
    scale_alpha_continuous(range= c(0, 1)) +
    coord_flip() + theme_bw()
```

[image]

In earlier versions of `ggplot2`, the plot showed "bands", but this problem has now apparently been fixed.

[image]

Comment: Hm, I noticed some of those bands in my version as well, but they're a lot more obvious with your version. My guess is that they have something to do with the segments overlapping a little. I tried playing with the `linejoin` and `lineend` in the geom code, but I didn't succeed in making the bands away.

Comment: I tried to overcome the banding problem by changing the size argument, so that each segment overlaps its neighbor to a greater degree, but found no satisfactory solution. That said, this is the best attempt I've seen so far, so thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It actually is possible, by using some tricks with `stat_ydensity`:

```
library(ggplot2)
theData <- data.frame(category <- sample(LETTERS[1:3], 1000, replace = T),
                  value <- rnorm(1000))

ggplot(theData, aes(x = category, y = value)) +
    stat_ydensity(geom="line", aes(alpha=..scaled..), size=2, trim=FALSE) +
    scale_alpha_continuous(range= c(0, 1)) +
    coord_flip() + theme_bw()
```

Comment: this doesn't look right, does the code need an update?